# How to view SVG's code in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I've been searching and I can't find out how to view the *code* of the SVG we have designed in Illustrator.  Does anyone know how?  I'm relatively new to Illustrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File -> Save As, Format SVG, Save

Click on the SVG Code button. This should open a new window in a text document.

Comment: Worth noting that the 'SVG Code' button isn't available if you check 'use artboards' in the previous dialog (not sure why).

Comment: Indeed that works. But is there a shortcut key to see the current code without having to save As etc?  Thanks!

Comment: @sam not that I have seen.

Comment: Yeah @Cai not sure either why it won't allow to show the code when checking "use artboards" but an easy workaround is to crop what's not part of the artboard by drawing a rectangle the same size on top and using  Object > Path > Divide Objects Below.